# Role with the same name as system role can be created in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

Syetem role "member" and "owner" can be created:

```
public ❯ create role owner;
Query took 0.008 seconds.
public ❯ drop role owner;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010076","error_message":"Couldn't Drop System Role owner"}
public ❯ select * from information_schema.roles;
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| role_name | role_type | inherit_role |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| owner     | system    |              |
| member    | system    |              |
| owner     | custom    | member       |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

I think this should be banned in cnosdb as it can lead to confusion.